# Which udev rules get executed for USB device?

Tags: linux, udev

I am new to udev. 
I need to see which rules are executed for USB device plugged in to linux machine.
Is there any logging provided by udev?

Comment: Answer at https://superuser.com/a/1501568/111302

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what

```
udevadm trigger --verbose ...
```

will tell you. It'll trigger a re-evaluation of the udev rules and you can use the other flags such as `--subsystem-match` and `--attr-match` to narrow down your USB device.

[man udevadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm)

And to find these attributes of your USB device use

```
lsusb -v
```

Comment: It didnt tell which rules executed for this usb device?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: `udevadm test /dev/bus/usb/001/045`

Comment: I tried this, it show as "read rules file" and displaying all the rule files. I need like exactly which rule file is executed for this device. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: All the files displayed by `udevadm test `... are read for every device. However, only matching lines in each file are used for each device.

Comment: @Mathias My answer was not intended as any critique or request for clarification, only an attempt to show a way to list used udev rule files. What does my answer lack to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Carlqvist's answer is correct but it leaves out most of the details.
From a real life case...

Problem:
My USB Keyboard is working in my gNewsense setup but my SourceMage.  So following is me trying to figure out what udev rules in gNewsense apply to this keyboard.

1) Get basic info

```
# lsusb
[...omitted...]
Bus 007 Device 006: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
[...omitted...]
```

So now I know...

The USB device node (not the same as keyboard device) is /dev/bus/usb/007/006
The idVendor=413c and the idProduct=2003 And if the keyboard didn't have any logos or stamps I would have human friendly text to search on.

Nowadays, keyboard and mice are under /dev/input/*, this is just something you have to know or gleem from webpages.  I got lucky and there is /dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd

Which in my case is a sym link to /dev/input/event0

2) This will get the 'other' device path (kernel or udev internal) for the keyboard

```
# udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input9/event0
```

3) Now, what rules happened to make this keyboard work?

Note that grep'ing for the idVendor and idProduct may be enough but there are typically wild cards and default builtin cases that do most of the work.

The **udevadm test** command will tell you all the rules, in the order that they are handled during this event (the event of plugging the USB keyboard into the USB connector).

Lines starting with **parse_file** show you the rules scripts files that actually got hooked into (e)udev in the order that they got read (lower number prefix should be first).  This is normally is a crap ton files, so ignore them for now.

Lines starting with **udev_node_mknod** are of interest because that's when udev actually makes the device node.

Lines startings with **udev_rules_apply_to_event** are probably what you're interested in.  It give the rule script file and the line number of rule triggering some change in udev.

So here is my output.  There will be a lot of noise (which I have omitted) but you can still trace through and see the creation of the dev nodes

```
# udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input9/event0
[...]
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id', replacing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules:78
[...]
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin 'input_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:4
[...]
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
[...]
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:7
builtin_usb_id: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0: if_class 3 protocol 0
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR=Dell
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Dell
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_VENDOR_ID=413c
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL=Dell_USB_Keyboard
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ENC=Dell\x20USB\x20Keyboard
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_MODEL_ID=2003
[...]
udev_rules_apply_to_event: LINK 'input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:24
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:31
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:1:1.0
udev_builtin_add_property: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_1-usb-0_1_1_0
udev_rules_apply_to_event: LINK 'input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:33
udev_rules_apply_to_event: IMPORT builtin skip 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules:13
udev_event_execute_rules: no node name set, will use kernel supplied name 'input/event0'
udev_node_add: creating device node '/dev/input/event0', devnum=13:64, mode=01600, uid=0, gid=0
udev_node_mknod: preserve file '/dev/input/event0', because it has correct dev_t
udev_node_mknod: preserve permissions /dev/input/event0, 021600, uid=0, gid=0
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/13:64' to '../input/event0'
link_find_prioritized: found 'c13:64' claiming '/run/udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd'
link_update: creating link '/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' to '/dev/input/event0'
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' to '../event0'
link_find_prioritized: found 'c13:64' claiming '/run/udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd'
link_update: creating link '/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd' to '/dev/input/event0'
node_symlink: preserve already existing symlink '/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd' to '../event0'
udev_device_update_db: created db file '/run/udev/data/c13:64' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input9/event0'
.INPUT_CLASS=kbd
ACTION=add
[...]
[end]
```

Comment: `udevadm` can be called with the `--debug` flag to have additional lines. So something like that: `udevadm --debug test /devices/pci0....`